# How to delete a document when multiple conditions are matched, firestore firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a firestore object when multiple conditions are matched.
Like below

```
db.collection('facilityOwners').where('facilityId', '==', facilityId).where('ownerId', '==', ownerId).delete()
```

In my facilityOwners collection 
[image]

I want to delete a document when these two properties are matched.
And I dont want to find the documents first and then perform the delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only write (and thus delete) a document in Firestore if you know the complete, exact path to that document. Firestore does not support the equivalent of SQL's `DELETE FROM facilityOwners WHERE ...` queries.

This means that you will first have to `get()` the results of the query, loop through them, and delete each document individually, or in batches. Something like:

```
let query = db.collection('facilityOwners').where('facilityId', '==', facilityId).where('ownerId', '==', ownerId);
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
});
```

Also see:

- [Cloud Firestore Swift: How to delete a query of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792471/cloud-firestore-swift-how-to-delete-a-query-of-documents)
- [How to delete document from firestore using where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180076/how-to-delete-document-from-firestore-using-where-clause/47180442#47180442)